# function (x,y), both x and y to vary

Tags: r, variables, count, apply

I have a data frame consisting of about 22 fields, some system ids and some measurements, such as

```
 bsystemid    dcesystemid  lengthdecimal  heightquantity  
 2218          58          22              263
 2219          58          22              197
 2220          58          22              241
```

What I want:

1 . loop through a list of field ids

2 . define a function to test for a condition

3 . such that both x and y can vary

Where does the y variable definition belong, for varying both x and y? Other different structures?

This code block works for a single field and value of y:

```
 varlist4<-names(brg) [c(6)]
 f1<-(function(x,y) count(brg[,x]<y) )
 lapply(varlist4, f1, y=c(7.5))
```

This code block executes, but the counts are off:

```
 varlist4<-names(brg) [c(6,8,10,12)]
 f1<-(function(x,y) count(brg[,x]<y) )
 lapply(varlist4, f1, y=c(7.5,130,150,0))
```

For example,

```
 varlist4<-names(brg) [c(6)]
 f1<-(function(x,y) count(brg[,x]<y) )
 lapply(varlist4, f1, y=c(7.5))
```

returns (correctly),

```
       x freq
 1 FALSE 9490
 2  TRUE  309
 3    NA   41
```

whereas the multiple x,y block of code above returns this for the first case,

```
      x freq
 1 FALSE 4828
 2  TRUE 4971
 3    NA   41
```

Thanks for any comments.

Update:

What I would like is to automate counting of occurances of values in specified fields in a df, meeting some condition.  The conditions are numeric constants or text strings, one for each field.  For example, I might want to count occurances meeting the condition >360 in field1, >0 in field2, etc.  What I thus mean by allowing x and y to vary is reading x and y vectors with the field names and corresponding conditions into a looping structure.

I'd like to automate this task because it involves around 30 tables, each with up to 50 or so fields.  And I'll need to do it twice, scanning once for values exceeding a maximum and once for values less than a minimum.  Better still might be loading the conditions into a table and referencing that in the loop.  That may be the next step but I'd like to understand this piece first.

This working example

```
 t1<-18:29
 t2<-c(76.1,77,78.1,78.2,78.8,79.7,79.9,81.1,81.2,81.8,82.8,83.5)
 t3<-c(1.2,-0.2,-0.3,1.2, 2.2,0.4,0.6,0.4,-0.8,-0.1,5.0,3.1)
 t<-data.frame(v1=t1,v2=t2,v3=t3)
 varlist<-names(t) [c(1)]
 f1<-(function(x,y) count(t[,x]>y) )
 lapply(varlist, f1, y=c(27))
```

illustrates the correct answer for the first field, returning

```
       x freq
 1 FALSE   10
 2  TRUE    2
```

But if I add in other fields and the corresponding conditions (the y's) I get something different for the first case:

```
 varlist<-names(t) [c(1,2,3)]
 f1<-(function(x,y) count(t[,x]>y) )
 lapply(varlist, f1, y=c(27,83,3))


       x freq
 1 FALSE    8
 2  TRUE    4

 [[2]]
       x freq
 1 FALSE    1
 2  TRUE   11

 [[3]]
      x freq
 1 FALSE   11
 2  TRUE    1
```

My sense is I'm not going about structuring the y part correctly.

Thanks for any comments.

Comment: I can't follow your example. Please produce a working example.

Comment: Sounds like you need `mapply`?

Comment: ok, I'll review mapply.

Comment: What is the function "count"?

Comment: Your working example has 12 rows, that's why you are not detecting a mistake in your code. Increase the example to have 13 rows and you will see the warnings.

Comment: ok.  Longer object length not multiple of shorter object length.

Comment: yes, @user2009447. R was recycling the elements of y to make the comparison with x, it was not using each element in y to make the comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapply`. Let's create some data:

```
set.seed(123) # to get exactly the same results
brg = data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100), z=rnorm(100))
brg$x[c(10, 15)] = NA  # some NAs
brg$y[c(12, 21)] = NA  # more NAs
```

Then you need to define the function to do the job. The function `.f1` counts the data, and ensure there are always three levels (TRUE, FALSE, NA). Then, `f1` uses `.f1` in an `mapply` context to be able to vary `x` and `y`. Finally, some improvements in the output (changing the names of the columns).

```
f1 = function(x, y, data) {

  .f1 = function(x, y, data) {
    out = factor(data[, x] < y, 
                 levels=c("TRUE", "FALSE", NA), exclude=NULL)
    return(table(out))
  }

  out = mapply(.f1, x, y, MoreArgs = list(data = data)) # check ?mapply
  colnames(out) = paste0(x, "<", y) # more clear names for the output
  return(out)
}
```

Finally, the test:

```
varlist   = names(brg)
threshold = c(0, 1, 1000)

f1(x=varlist, y=threshold, data=brg)
```

And you should get

```
      x<0 y<1 z<1000
TRUE   46  87    100
FALSE  52  11      0
<NA>    2   2      0
```

Comment: ok, I'll review mapply.  I've provided a working example and further comment above.

Comment: I think my answer is exactly what are you looking for, or I'm not getting your problem at all.

Comment: That's neat, much better than my approach.  Works beautifully, applies to entire df.  Saves me a lot of work.